# Convexity of Certain Functions

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the set of functions:
\begin{equation}
f_n(t) := t^n e^{(\frac{c}{t^n})},
\end{equation}
where $c$ is a non-zero real constant.

I know that for $n=1$ $f_1(t)$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$ and when I graphed memebers of this family they all *"look like"* they're convex on the $(0,\infty])$.

My question is: is this indeed true?
If not which members are convex?

Comment: What does "Orthogonality" have to do with this?

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking of something else when I typed the original title... fixed it now (I can be abit abscent minded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the second derivative, we find that $f_n$ (for $n > 0$) is convex when

$$ (n-1) t^{2n}-c (n-1)t^n +c^2 n \ge 0$$

The left side is a quadratic $Q(s)$ in $s = t^n$.
If $n > 1$, the minimum of the quadratic occurs at $s =  c/2$, with $Q(c/2) = (3n+1) c^2/4 > 0$.  Thus it is indeed convex.

On the other hand, if $0 < n < 1$, the left side is negative, making the function concave, for sufficiently large $t$.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: as the function is $C^\infty$ you can check if the second derivative is always positive or not. Now, the second derivative is given by
$$f_n''(x)=e^{c x^{-n}} n x^{-2-n} (c^2 n-c (-1+n) x^n+(-1+n) x^{2 n}),$$
and as the first terms are positive you only need to check if the expression in the parenthesis is always positive

Comment: So the answer is yes for c<0?

Comment: See Robert's answer ;)